# Python threading в цикле

Tags: python, ssh, pthread, paramiko

мне нужен скрипт, который бы подключался по SSH на железки (МСЭ), вводил на них команду show arp-table  забирал арп таблицу и записывал ее в БД.
Железок много (800+), поэтому я хочу написать скрипт на потоках.
Столкнулся с проблемой : при потоках со временем сдыхает ssh библиотека paramiko(потому что я не могу контролировать поток), а без потоков сдыхает со временем  библиотека mysql, потому что я постоянно открываю закрываю соединение.

Список железок cpbase, он в формате
железка - ip

Вот код:

```
import paramiko
from datetime import datetime
import  mysql.connector as mysqldb
from warnings import filterwarnings
from socket import error as socket_error
import netaddr
import os
import time
import threading


def ssh_connect(fqdn, host, user, secret, port, command):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=secret, port=port)
    print("executing command arp -a\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    time.sleep(5)
    while not stdout.channel.eof_received:
        time.sleep(10)
        if time.time() > endtime:
            stdout.channel.close()
            print(fqdn + " " + host + " " + "closing connection because of timeout\n")
            with open(logfile, 'a+') as log:
                log.write(fqdn + " " + host + " " + "closing connection because of timeout(MTU Problem!)\n")
            break
    data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
    data = data.strip()
    #command_exit
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command_exit)
    #print(data)
    client.close()
    return data
def main(cpbase):
    ip_mac_list = []
    for item in cpbase:
        hostname = item.split(",")[0].replace("(", '').strip()
        ip = item.split(",")[1].replace(")",'').strip()
        print(hostname + " " + ip + " " + "trying to get ip arp table...\n")
        arp_file_of_dev = hostname + "_" + ip + "_" + "arp_table.txt"
        if '1430' or '1450' or '1470' or '1490' in hostname:
            try:
                print(hostname + " " + ip  + " trying...")
                arp  = ssh_connect(hostname, ip, login_gw, pass_gw, port, command_show_arp_1430)
            if len(arp) == 0:
                    pass
                else:
                    with open(arp_file_of_dev, 'a+') as arp_file:
                    arp_file.write(arp)
            ip_mac = clear_conf_file(arp_file_of_dev)
                    #insert_ip_mac(ip, mac)
                    ip_mac_list.append(ip_mac)
                    with open("ip_mac_file.txt", "a") as ipmf:
                        ipmf.write(ip_mac + "\n")
        except socket_error as serr:
            print(hostname + " " + ip  + " some error..." +  str(serr) + "\n")
            with open(logfile, 'a') as log:
                    log.write(hostname + " " +  ip  + " some error..." +  str(serr) + "\n")
            continue
        elif '3200' or '5200' or '5400' or '5600' or '5800' or '15400'in hostname:
            try:
                print(hostname + " " + ip + "trying...")
            arp  = ssh_connect(hostname, ip, login_gw, pass_gw, port, command_show_arp_3200)
            if (len(arp)) == 0:
                pass
            else:
                with open(arp_file_of_dev, 'a+') as arp_file:
                    arp_file.write(arp)
            ip_mac = clear_conf_file_3200(arp_file_of_dev)
                    #insert_ip_mac(ip, mac)
                    ip_mac_list.append(ip_mac)
                    with open("ip_mac_file.txt", "a") as ipmf:
                        ipmf.write(ip_mac + "\n")
        except socket_error as serr:
            print(hostname + " " + ip  + " some error..." +  str(serr) + "\n")
            with open(logfile, 'a') as log:
                log.write(hostname + " " +  ip  + " some error..." +  str(serr) + "\n")
                continue
    return ip_mac_list


start = time.time()
print(start)
thread_list = []
#main script function
#write via threading
ip_mac_list = threading.Thread(target=main, args=[cpbase]).start()
while threading.activeCount() > 1: time.sleep(1)
ip_mac_list.join()
end = time.time()
print("time taken {}".format(end-start))
print("all threads done")
```

cpbase - это список железок в формате hostname + ip.
Сейчас функция main принимает весь этот список и идет по нему, из за этого потока по сути нет, т.к. функция сама идет по списку.
Я пытался переписать вот так:

```
for item in cpbase:
    ip_mac_list = threading.Thread(target=main, args=[item]).start()
```

Тогда потоки запускаются для всех 800 железок, но скрипт перестает быть контролируемым, либо загибается библиотека paramiko, либо зависают какие то подключения потому что я больше не могу писать в функции вот так:

```
except socket_error as serr:
                print(hostname + " " + ip  + " some error..." +  str(serr) + "\n")
                with open(logfile, 'a') as log:
                    log.write(hostname + " " +  ip  + " some error..." +  str(serr) + "\n")
                    continue
```

так как continue уже находится вне цикла.

Большая просьба подсказать как бы вы переписали этот код чтобы можно было контролировать число потоков и в то же время получить приемлимую скорость
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Допустим у Вас есть файл: `creds.txt` и в нем есть записи типа:

```
192.168.1.104:335;user;mirko
192.168.1.105:22;pasha;pasha
...
```

В основе лежит asyncio. Писал без возможности проверить, на коленке.

```
import asyncio
import asyncssh
from async_timeout import timeout as ftime
from aiofiles import open as afile


COMMAND = 'lsb_release -a'


async def save_reply(ip, reply):
    async with afile(f'{ip}.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8',
                         errors='ignore') as f:
            await f.write(str(reply))


async def connect(ip, user, passw):
    try:
        async with asyncssh.connect(ip, username=user, password=passw) as c:
            result = await conn.run(COMMAND, check=True)
            await save_reply(ip, result.stdout)
    except asyncssh.Error:
        print('Error with', ip)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Another error in', ip, e)


async def start():
    tasks = []

    async with afile('creds.txt', errors="ignore",
                     encoding="utf-8") as data:
        async for entry in data:
            user, login, passw = data.split(';', 2)

            task = asyncio.create_task(
                connect(
                    ip,
                    user,
                    passw.strip()
                )
            )
            tasks.append(task)

            if len(tasks) >= threads:
                await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
                tasks = []

    if len(tasks) != 0:
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threads = int(input('Threads: '))
    timeout = int(input('Timeout: '))

    asyncio.run(start())
```